# Monoid unit as unit of some adjunction

Tags: category-theory

Is there any way of regarding the units coming from a monoidal category $\mathscr{C}$, as the units of some adjoint functors? What would the involved functors be? I assume these functors would be satisfy either $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$ or $F:\mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: The monoidal unit is an object, whereas the unit and counit of an adjunction are natural transformations. So it’s unclear how to match these up. You may be interested in learning about dualizable objects in monoidal categories.

Comment: Maybe by "unit" you mean "unitor" ? i.e. the maps $X\to 1\otimes X$ ? Then they can indeed be seen (although it's a little weird and I can't see how useful that would be) as the unit of the adjunction $id\dashv 1\otimes-$ (because $1\otimes -$ is isomorphic to $id$, so it is indeed right adjoint to $id$)